# Including library functions into WPF design paradigm

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Given a basic C# library, how do I implement functions of this library into my WPF application to handle appropriately the concepts of Binding and Commands?

I mean, need I write some own wrappers for these library classes in order to implement interfaces such as `ICommand` or should this be done directly in the library itself?

Some code to get my question more comprehensible:

From the library:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void DoSomething() { throw new NotImplementedException; }
}
```

I want to implement the function DoSomething() in my XAML markup without any line of code in that .cs file since that is, from what I've read, the best practice.

(Assuming that an instance of Item is bound to the control)

```
<Button Command="{Binding DoSomething}"/>
```

Well, in order to do so, I need to implement the interface `ICommand` and create a command, but that is, as stated above, unclear to me since I'm using a library here.

Should I write my own Wrapper for the Item class of the API and implement the `ICommand` interface or is there any other way to archieve this? I've written the library by myself so changes are possible. I'm just not entirely sure about changing the library because if I do so, it is (possibly) bound to WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi there if anything your `ViewModel` should handle any requests on your `Model` that's it's sole purpose, to get these things to work you need ICommand and if you want some more info here is [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28093/Using-RoutedCommands-with-a-ViewModel-in-WPF) with a tutorial on `RoutedCommands`. If you have your `Model` and `ViewModel` defined then you can easily assign tasks to the particular `Model` through its `VM`.

P.S. I think you could treat your library as a `Model` and write a "wrapper" `ViewModel` to handle operations on it. HTH

**UPDATE**

Consider following:

```
class libClass
{
     void method()
     {
         //do something here
     }
}
```

code above would be your model and if you want it to be more readable you could do it this way

```
class libModel
{
     private libClass _libClass;

     public libClass LibClass { get; set; }
}
```

**Note**

You could implement INotfiyPropertyChanged in your Model to handle  any changes if needed of course.

now in your `VM` how you use the `Model`

```
class ViewModel
{
 private libModel _libModel;
 public libModel LibModel { get; set; }
 //after you set up your RoutedCommands
 //I declare method within my VM to handle the RoutedCommands don't know 
 //if it works when you use Property Method
 void VMMethod()
 {
      //use VM's property to invoke desired method from your lib
 }
}
```

and voila! ready "wrapper" for your class with implementation in your VM.

**Tip**

If you want to know how to do the `RoutedCommands` here is a [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28093/Using-RoutedCommands-with-a-ViewModel-in-WPF) to a tutorial.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer. Well, after some research on the `MVVM` pattern, this sounds really straightforward to me. However, could you provide a short example of how you'd wrap a class? Basically this shouldn't be a problem to me, I already have something in mind but I'd like to be sure on how to design this properly. Thanks for your efford.